# Nemo menu bar doesn't show up

Tags: nemo

I'm having this very weird issue with Nemo file manager (that I use to replace Nautilus).

When I make the menu bar appear (using Alt or right click on the top bar), and the click on any of the options (File, Edit etc...) the option menu appears then almost instantly disappears, and I can't figure out why.
The GIF doesn't even show the menu appearing.

Any ideas why ? This is really annoying...

[image: example]

On Ubuntu 20.04, Gnome 3.36.8.

Comment: Edited, Ubuntu 20.04 :)

Comment: As a workaround you can set menu to be shown always. Use View → Menubar for this.

Comment: Yeah but I can't access view...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround you can set menu to be shown always.
Use View → Menubar for this or programmatically:

```
gsettings set org.nemo.window-state start-with-menu-bar true
```

to revert use

```
gsettings set org.nemo.window-state start-with-menu-bar false
```